# ranking in a descending order in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to rank the variables in my dataset in a descending order of the Number of Plants used. I tried ranking in .csv and then exporting it in R. But even then, the plot was not ranked in the required order. Here is my dataset

```
df <- structure(list(Lepidoptera.Family = structure(c(3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 6L), 
   .Label = c("Hesperiidae", "Lycaenidae", "Nymphalidae", "Papilionidae", "Pieridae","Riodinidae"), class = "factor"),
           LHP.Families = c(55L, 55L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 1L)), 
    .Names = c("Lepidoptera.Family", "LHP.Families"), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

gg <- melt(df,id="Lepidoptera.Family", value.name="LHP.Families", variable.name="Type")

ggplot(gg, aes(x=Lepidoptera.Family, y=LHP.Families, fill=Type))+ 
       geom_bar(stat="identity")+
      coord_flip()+facet_grid(Type~.)
```

How do i rank them in a descending order? Also, i want to combine 3 plots into one. How can i go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that `ggplot` plots the x variables that are factors in the ordering of the underlying values (recall that factors are stored as numbers underneath the covers). If you want to graph them in an alternate order, you should change the order of the levels before plotting

```
gg$Lepidoptera.Family<-with(gg, 
                     factor(Lepidoptera.Family, 
                            levels=Lepidoptera.Family[order(LHP.Families)]))
```

Comment: to be fair I think @Paul Hiemstra 's answer below is nicer (the use of reorder is cleaner). I would suggest rejecting mine and accepting his.

Comment: +1 Your solution is perfectly valid, so the acceptance is fine.

Comment: I was unable to use @Paul Hiemstra's method. I did not know where to enter the command. I tried entering it after specifying the df, but then the plot was the same as original and was not ordered. 

Can i use the same command to order different columns in the same dataset and obtain corresponding plots with ordered values with same row names?

Comment: ah yes, it seems it is missing the final assignment into Lepidoptera.Family, I believe the full command should be 
df = within(df, 
  Lepidoptera.Family<-factor(Lepidoptera.Family, levels = reorder(Lepidoptera.Family, LHP.Families))
)     and yes, you should be able to do this for other factors

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to reorder the `levels` of the `Lepidoptera.Family` factor, which by default is alphabetical:

```
df = within(df, {
    factor(Lepidoptera.Family, levels = reorder(Lepidoptera.Family, LHP.Families))
})

gg <- melt(df,id="Lepidoptera.Family", value.name="LHP.Families", variable.name="Type")
ggplot(gg, aes(x=Lepidoptera.Family, y=LHP.Families, fill=Type))+ geom_bar(stat="identity")+ coord_flip()+facet_grid(Type~.)
```

[image]